# iconv() returns NA when given a string with a specific special character

Tags: r, character-encoding, ascii, iconv

I am trying to convert some strings of an input file from UTF8 to ASCII. For most of the strings I give it, the conversion works perfectly fine with `iconv()`. However on some of them, it returns `NA`. While manually fixing the issue in the file seems like the simplest option, it is unfortunately not an option that I have available at the moment at all.

I have made a reproducible example of my problem but we assume to assume that I have to figure a way for `iconv()` to somehow convert the string in `s1` and not get `NA`.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
s1 <- "Besançon" #as read from an input file I cannot modify
s2 <- "Paris"
s3 <- "Linköping"
s4 <- "Besançon" #Manual input for testing

s1 <- iconv(s1, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
s2 <- iconv(s2, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
s3 <- iconv(s3, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
s4 <- iconv(s4, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
```

I get the following output:

```
> s1
[1] NA
> s2
[1] "Paris"
> s3
[1] "Link\"oping"
> s4
[1] "Besancon"
```

After playing around with the code, I figured that something was wrong in the entry "Besançon" that is now copied exactly from the input file. When I input it manually myself, the problem is solved. Since I can't modify the input file at all, what do you think is the exact issue and would you have any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Edit:

After closer inspection, there is something odd in the characters of the first line. It seems to be taken away by SO's formatting.
But to reproduce it, the best I could give is these two images describing it. First image places my cursor just before the #
Second image is after pressing delete, which should delete the white space... turns out it deletes the ". So there is definitely something weird there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to transliterate `s1`. Changing the command to `s1 <- iconv(s1, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')` works as required.

Comment: @thorepet that's an error in my copy paste. I already had that in. Edit on the way. Still does not work

Comment: New edit to show that there is definitely something wrong in my initial input for s1. @thorepet so the issue was definitely not in my copy paste

Comment: What happens when you specify a `sub`? Is the `iconvlist()` from the system you don't control the same as your local(e)?

Comment: @Chris what sub do you want me to specify, not sure I understand your question

Comment: Just following from the ?iconv `Elements of ‘x’ which cannot be converted (perhaps because they are invalid or because they cannot be represented in the target encoding) will be returned as ‘NA’ unless ‘sub’ is specified.` which may seem unintuitive given your `s3` `/`, but perhaps specifying a sub, sub = '/' gets your uncontrolled file working. Just a thought.

Comment: Please share the following `Encoding(s1)  <- "bytes"; print(s1)` (output).

Comment: @JosefZ 'Encoding(s1)  <- "bytes"; print(s1)' gives NA too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that using `sub=''` actually solved the issue although I am quite unsure why.

```
iconv(s1, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT', sub='')
```

From the documentation `sub`

> character string. If not NA it is used to replace any non-convertible
> bytes in the input. (This would normally be a single character, but
> can be more.) If "byte", the indication is "" with the hex code of
> the byte. If "Unicode" and converting from UTF-8, the Unicode point in
> the form "<U+xxxx>".

So I eventually figured out that there was a character I couldn't convert (nor see) in the string and using sub was a way to eliminate it. I am still not sure what this character is though. But the problem is solved.

Comment: This seems reasonable logic that iconv would try conversion based upon all options available and failing being able to convert to error, signalling the embedded unconvertable. `sub` then functions as 'if all else fails',  use this. Depending on your data pipeline and research needs you might further decide on a symbol you can see, i.e. '+' or '/', if you are tracking where it propagated from, Glad it solved.

Comment: @Chris yeah I can't seem to be able to track where this is coming from and I did this trick of sub='+' to see where it was. Now I know where it is, but still can't see what the actual character is... At least it's solved!

Comment: Which leads to @webb 's approach if it is really of concern.

Comment: It seems almost certain to be a control character. Here is a way to find these in your input data https://superuser.com/a/377805/1280908

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a latin1 (or other encoding) character in your supposedly utf8 file. For example:

```
> latin=iconv('Besançon','utf8','latin1')
> iconv(latin,to='ascii//translit')
[1] NA
> iconv(latin,'utf8','ascii//translit')
[1] NA
> iconv(latin,'latin1','ascii//translit')
[1] "Besancon"
> iconv(l,'Windows-1250','ascii//translit')
[1] "Besancon"
```

You can e.g. make one new vector or data column with the result of each character set encoding in your data, and if one is NA, fall back to the next one, e.g.

```
utf8 = iconv(x,'utf8','ascii//translit')
latin1 = iconv(x,'latin1','ascii//translit')
win1250 = iconv(x,'Windows-1250','ascii//translit')
result = ifelse(
  is.na(utf8),
  ifelse(
    is.na(latin1),
    win1250,
    latin1
  ),
  utf8
)
```

If these encodings don't work, make a file with just the problem word, then use the unix/linux `file` command to detect the encoding, or else try some likely encodings.

I have in the past just listed all of iconv's supported encodings, tried all with lapply, and then used whichever results worked on each string, but some "from" encodings will return a non-NA but incorrect result, so it's best to try this on each unique character in your data in order to decide which subset of iconv's encodings to use and in which order.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion. Both R and the file command suggest that this is utf-8 but none of the methods you proposed work. I would tend to think that something is broken in the input (see my images edit) and I can't seem to be able to figure out what it is.